# Text randomly won't word wrap iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, word-wrap

I have a table where the label in the cell word wraps and the height of the cell is dynamically set accordingly. Some cells, seemingly at random, will truncate instead. These rogue cells are still the expanded height needed for the extra lines that should be there.

I have tried to do this programmatically and through the Interface Builder. Same results both times.

This is the perfect example. There are at least two cells that ARE word wrapped. The one circled in red is an example of one of my rogue cells.

[image]

I would like even a pointer to where the problem may lie, as I don't know where to start.

Comment: Just realized this started when I added the custom font last night. Remove that and everything works. Apologies for inadequate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is each line a separate UILabel? UILabels dont automatically handle line breaks very well (in my experience).  For that, i suggest you try out UITextView.

Comment: If this is not an option, then why is it presented in the inspector? Line Breaks : Word Wrap

Comment: Good question, what i really shouldve said was they dont handle line breaks very well, at least not in my experience.  Try setting a smaller minimum font size.

Comment: Still randomly refuses to word wrap with smaller font size. I'm just going to tell my graphics people the custom font is screwing it up. You are right about UILaben not handling line breaks well.

Comment: @anijam Your code is adjusting the size of the table view cell the UILabel, presumably based upon `sizeWithFont`. Is that using your custom font, too?

Comment: Yes. I'm using heightForRowAtIndexPath based on the custom font. It's that some of them are truncating, seemingly at random.

Answer (score 1):

For a UILabel to automatically word wrap, try setting the numberOfLines property to 0.

Comment: Already set. Found out that this issue ONLY happens with the custom font I was given.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your screen snapshot (which is a little hard to make out because it was reduced), I notice that your table view cells are different heights, which leads me to assume if you're doing some `sizeWithFont` calculation to figure out the height of the cell and determining the frame for the `UILabel`. Are you sure you're specifying your custom font properly there? What `CGSize` are you using for the `constrain` parameter? And if you're not doing `sizeWithFont`, how are you getting cells of different heights?

I would have thought that the problem would not rest with `UILabel` vs `UITextView` (the latter can only introduce additional issues), but rather in your code that sets the frame for your label and sets the height of the table view cell.